# Running jquery slider simultaneously

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

here is my simple jquery ui code with html.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function () {
          $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
          $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000); 
    });
});
```

here goes html

```
<img src="images/logo.png"/>
```

The image is being hidden and then coming back, I want this thing be be simultaneous.

Note: you might suggest some similar questions, I check some of them out and none worked for me. Looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the cleanest approach, but you could just clone the item and then animate the cloned item:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var x = $(this).clone(true);

    $("body").append(x);

    $(this).hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    x.show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
});​
```

Comment: Some problems are there, but this thing over all works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example and needs adjustments but I think you can get the idea.

HTML

```
<img id="img1" src="image1.jpg">
<img id="img2" src="image2.jpg">
```

CSS

```
img{
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  position: absolute;
}
#img1{
  left:0;
}
#img2{
  left:250px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$("#img1").click(function() { 
   $("#img1").animate({left: '-250px'},2000); 
   $("#img2").animate({left: '0'},2000); 
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jur4x/3htpr/7/)
​